# What is this insect found swarming in my unmanaged garden?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, garden

I’ve an unmanaged garden outside my apartment. It used to have several shrubs and pine straw, but the owners ripped them out and now they just trim the weeds every few weeks. They trimmed a week and a half ago, and today I observed these insects swarming on the ground throughout the garden. The largest specimens observed are no more than 3mm long. I am located in south east Georgia, USA, about an hour inland from Savannah.

Wingless nymph, underside:
[image]
Wingless nymph, face:
[image]
Wingless nymph, top side:
[image]
Winged adult, underside
[image]
Winged adult, face:
[image]
Winged adult, top side:
[image]
Winged adult, top face:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this SE. For ID questions, we need a) clear pictures of the object and b) a size indication. Based on what I can see at the moment - it is an insect, but can't make out much else

Comment: @bob1 Thanks, I’ve a microscope camera at work, I’ll collect a few specimens and get better pictures tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. First impression was stink-bug (brown marmorated?), but I don't know enough about the instars to be sure.

Comment: @bob1 How are the pictures now?

Comment: @Bob1  I'm not an expert, but it looks too skinny to be a stink bug, at least not the variety in Northern VA.  Also 3 mm is shorter than the stink bugs I know.

Comment: @ab2 And much smaller than the stinkbugs I'm familiar with here in Georgia.

Comment: @ab - on the clearer photos, definitely not stinkbug. No idea what it is at all.

Answer (score 3):

It appears it may be a Nysius Raphanus (false chinch bug).
Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nysius_raphanus):

> Nysius Raphanus (false chinch bug) are a small North American insect, no larger than 1/8th inch (3.175mm). They are often grey to brown in color, with largely transparent wings, and can release an offensive odor similar to stinkbugs. They have no larval stage, instead going through several nymph stages with the nymphs resembling adults but having no wings. In high numbers false chinch bugs can cause significant plant damage.

[image: https://inaturalist-open-data.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/2761915/original.jpg]

[image]

source: https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/ORN/TURF/false_chinch_bug.html